# python code is restarting

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

as I'm proceeding slowly with project Euler I started learning python.
although its a great and simple language i got a bit stuck.

every code that i wrote and tried to run is automatically restarting.
i think its because of the very very long loop (for example, finding the 10001 prime number), but i cant find out how to fix this issue.
can anyone help me, give me a guide line or a tip?

oh, if its matters im using python 2.7

thank you!

the code as an example:

```
count = 0
num = 0
i = 1
def prime(num):
    if num <= 1:
        return False
    if num == 2:
        return True
    else:
        for i in range(3, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                return False
                break
        else:
            return True

while (count < 10001):
    if prime(i) == True:
        num == i
        count == count + 1
    i = i + 1

print num
```

Comment: To explain the answer below, `==` is an equality while `=` is an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the `==` to `=` (twice) in your `while` loop:

```
while (count < 10001):
    if prime(i) == True:
        num = i
        count = count + 1
    i = i + 1
```

Then the code runs fine, and prints `num` as `104729`

Comment: can belive i did that ><
anyway the output in the shell is still:

================================ RESTART ================================

Comment: You are going to need to provide some more details. When I run your code with the two edits I suggested, I generate an answer.